# Screen frame render finished / presented callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, quartz-core

I'd like to know the exact moment when screen frame finishes rendering and gets displayed, so I can capture specific window images with quartz api. There is `CVDisplayLink` / `CADisplayLink` that allows application to synchronise its drawing to the refresh rate of the display.

As I understand, those methods are very similar to what I need, but invoked when screen frame needs to be rendered, not when it finished and presented, meaning that if I capture the current screen image at that time I'd only see the previous render. Is this correct thinking?

If yes, is there a way to do get notified when the frame has actually finished rendered and was presented? Maybe there's private api for that? Ideally I need an answer for macOS, but if you happen to know how to do this in iOS, please let know.

P.S. I'm aware of `CGDisplayStream`, it's a great solution for capturing the whole screen, not specific windows – it uses run loops and dispatch queues, meaning that callbacks are not invoked in realtime like with display links.

Comment: How about subclassing the view and overriding [draw:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw) method. As per documentation `By the time this method is called, UIKit has configured the drawing environment appropriately`. So an event generated in this method will be at the end of the default display sequence.

Comment: I need to capture what's just been drawn onto the screen, not to draw. There's no guarantee custom view will be the last item in draw queue, and even if it is, the drawn frame is unlikely to be displayed at this time, unless it draws directly to screen. Also, captured windows might be owned by other applications.

Comment: I don't understand why `CGDisplayStream` is not what you want.  It provides you a way to capture each frame of the screen when it is updated.  It makes no difference whether the call back happens in real time or not as the entire frame buffer is passed to you.  If you want to narrow your focus to individual windows it looks like you can use the backing conversion functions in NSScreen.  Why is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, like said, I need to capture specific windows, not entire screen. Captured window can be transparent, have irregular shape, have rounded corners – everything captured underneath transparent areas would need to be separated and is a huge task. So, extracting individual windows from display stream data is not a solution. Backing conversion is not a problem, but will be useless anyway if window is moved / resized during the capture, because of that very time factor – window frame in 3/4 cases will differ from the rendered one. That's what I'm currently getting and trying to avoid.